# Bottle framework writing a xls file

Tags: python, bottle, xlsxwriter

I need to create a display a xls file using the bottle framework.

Here is my current code, it opens a writes the content "Hello World"..My real word file will contain numerous rows..

How can I write all the contents efficiently?

My current view that prints a single cell in the xls sheet.

```
@app.route('/SimpleCSV',method='GET')
def createxls():
 xls = ""
    import StringIO
    import xlsxwriter
    output = StringIO.StringIO()

    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(output, {'in_memory':True})
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    worksheet.write(0,0,'Hello World')
    worksheet.write(0,1,'This is prem')
    workbook.close()

    output.seek(0)

    print 'Excel file created and now will be returned'
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet; charset=UTF-8'
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=text.xls'

    return output.read()
```

WOrking Code:

```
@bottle.route('/xl')
def create_xls():
    import StringIO
    import xlsxwriter
    output = StringIO.StringIO()

    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(output, {'in_memory':True})
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    for each in range(100):
        for each1 in range(100):
                worksheet.write(each,each1,"Test")
    workbook.close()

    output.seek(0)

    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet; charset=UTF-8'
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=text1.xlsx'
    return output.read()
```

Comment: Do you really need to make it real-time? I mean, why don't create the file beforehand?

Comment: You mean, create the excel file with output and pass it directly?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what are you trying to do. Just the first thought came up into my mind: you want to generate huge `xlsx` file in the bottle view which will result into forcing the user to wait. But, if you could prepare the file beforehand, then the user would just download the file without waiting for it to be prepared.

Comment: Also, take a look at [constant_memory](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/working_with_memory.html) argument: - might help to make generation faster.

Comment: Let me try that and keep you posted.

Comment: My concern is what will this stmt do?  Will it create a new Xls file or it will send the existing file, response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=text.xls'

Comment: It just sets a response header that tells the browser what's the attachment's name, that's it.

Comment: The whole report is generate in-memory and is written to the stringio buffer, then the buffer contents is returned - everything is in-memory.

Comment: So the actual file is never passed, correct?

Comment: Yup, no files are involved.

Comment: So how can I create a file beforehand?

Comment: Btwn thanks very much for ur comments, it helps me in understanding

Comment: Sure, it depends on how fresh do you need the data to be in the report, what is the source and how often do you need to "refresh"/regenerate the data in the xlsx file. Also, it depends on how often will this bottle view/function called and if the time to wait for the report matters. If the user wouldn't mind waiting for n seconds - then, ok, generate the file on the fly. So, please, tell me more about the task. Thanks.

Comment: The user has 3 options, create a XML, Xls and PDF document...there won't be much content in this Xls sheet... Hardly 50 rows...so I assume there won't be more wait time...now, the only concern how can I write the strong object in the Xls..

Comment: This is a game changer then - generating on the fly would be fast enough on 50 rows. Where is the data coming from? What format?

Comment: It's coming farm a web service call

Comment: its working..I have updated the code...Thanks much..Now, I need to figure out for pdf...:)